# How to setup Virtual Host for a sub domain?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I have a sub domain. I want to set up virtual host for it locally using xampp (apache).

For example I want to use test.mywebsite.com
I want to run local files by opening this sub domain.

I have tried almost all articles/helping meterials online to setup sub domain for virtual host but in vain.

I tried following but nothing work:

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/project"
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias test.mywebsite.com
```

**hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com
127.0.0.1 test.mywebsite.com
```

I'll appreciate for any suggestion/help.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 10

Comment: What did you try ? what is your current httpd.conf file ? and hosts file ?

Comment: So you're asking for subdomain? Well subdomains is basically just a folder inside your current directory. E.g: test.localhost.dev. You CANNOT use any official domain name. Such as .com, .org, .net, .gov, etc.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre I added my code above. Please check

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper I was successful in doing so for main domain "mywebsite.com" but for subdomain it works only if I disable my internet otherwise it picks up only live version.

Comment: @StackDeveloper That's exactly the point on why you cannot use live domains.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and add the following lines. Make sure to replace dir with your original document root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  test.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\dir"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\dir">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache then edit `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and add the following line at bottom.

`127.0.0.1    test.mywebsite.com`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried above but It still did not work. It works only if I disable my internet. Otherwise it picks up only live version.